# Datepicker button does not appear

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to design layout of my WPF windows to add some code list item and I need to use DatePicker, but calendar button is not visible in textbox.

this is my grid:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Code" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Code}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="160" MaxLength="30" MaxWidth="160" />

        <Label Content="Description" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="160" MaxLength="120" MaxWidth="160" />

        <Label Content="Valid from" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
        <DatePicker Name="dpValidFrom" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />

        <Label Content="Valid to" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
        <DatePicker Name="dpValidTo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

In design mode a see this:

[image: In design mode a see this]

but in app i see this:
[image: but in app i see this]

have someone idea why?
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any problems using Windows 10 VS 2015. Though, based on your screen shot, it looks like there is some type of default `Margin` or `Padding`. Use this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Label Content="Code" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Code}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="160" MaxLength="30" MaxWidth="160" />

    <Label Content="Description" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="160" MaxLength="120" MaxWidth="160" />

    <Label Content="Valid from" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
    <DatePicker Name="dpValidFrom" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />

    <Label Content="Valid to" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <DatePicker Name="dpValidTo" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```